# FadeIn FadeOut happens only when website is opened REACT JSX

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

How to set proper classes for CSS animations , so they work every time I quote is being generated to display? If the css animations are not the problem, then what is?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
    import styles from './QuoteDisplay.module.css';
    import { EmberModeContext } from '../styles/EmberMode';
    import { baseQuotes, emberQuotes } from './Quotes';

const QuoteDisplay = () => {
  const { isEmberMode } = useContext(EmberModeContext);
  const [quote, setQuote] = useState({
    quote: '',
    author: '',
    reference: '',
    enumeration: '',
  });
  const [animate, setAnimate] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const addEnumeration = (quotes) => {
      return quotes.map((quote, index) => ({
        ...quote,
        enumeration: (index + 1).toString(),
      }));
    };

    const getRandomQuote = () => {
      let quotes;
      if (isEmberMode) {
        quotes = [...baseQuotes, ...addEnumeration(emberQuotes)];
      } else {
        quotes = baseQuotes;
      }

      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
      return quotes[randomIndex];
    };

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setAnimate(true); // Trigger the animation by toggling the animate state

      setTimeout(() => {
        setQuote((prevQuote) => ({
          ...getRandomQuote(),
        }));
      }, 500); // Adjust the delay as per your preference

      setTimeout(() => {
        setAnimate(false); // Reset the animate state after the animation
      }, 1000); // Adjust the delay as per your preference
    }, 4000);

    setQuote(getRandomQuote());

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [isEmberMode]);

  return (
    <div className={`quote-container ${isEmberMode ? styles.emberMode : ''}`}>
      {quote.enumeration && quote.reference === 'Dokkodo' && (
        <p className={styles.enumeration}>
          {quote.enumeration}.&nbsp;
        </p>
      )}
      <p
        id="quote"
        className={`${styles.quote} ${animate ? styles.fadeIn : ''}`}
      >
        {quote.reference === 'Dokkodo' && (
          <span className={styles.enumeration}>
            {quote.enumeration}.&nbsp;
          </span>
        )}
        "{quote.quote}"
      </p>
      {quote.author && (
        <p className={styles.author}>
          - {quote.author}
          {quote.reference && (
            <span className={styles.reference}>
              ({quote.reference})
            </span>
          )}
        </p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default QuoteDisplay;
```

CSS File :

```
.quote-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  .quote-wrapper {
    max-width: 600px; /* Adjust the width as per your preference */
  }
  
  .quote {
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out;
    animation: fadeIn 0.5s ease-in-out forwards;
  }
  
  .samurai-quote {
    font-family: 'JapaneseFont', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
  }
  
  .hindu-quote {
    font-family: 'HindiFont', sans-serif;
    font-size: 28px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
  }
  
  .emberMode .quote {
    color: #c55d17;
    text-shadow: 0 0 12px #d54b00;
  }
  
  .quote {
    color: #bb73df;
    text-shadow: 0 0 12px #8800cb;
  }
  
  .emberMode .author,
  .author {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #ffa500;
  }
  
  .emberMode .reference {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #ffa500;
  }
  
  @keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  
  @keyframes fadeOut {
    from {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
```

I want to generate the pleasant experience of displaying the quotes , in a manner that allows user to read that quote, experience the moment of realization of the though inside the head and then change it spontaneously to another quote. this generator will operate on 2,3 different context displaying various kinds of quotes (not some motivational speeches), more like more informative stuff, displaying the area of interests.